# Two characters with the most synergy

Tags: overwatch

I have this friend who I like to play Overwatch with.

Normally we just pick random heroes that our team may need or heroes we like playing. We are starting to play a bit more and getting better so we are starting to work more on teamwork, and we are starting to think more critically about our character selection.

Because there could be countless strategies between the different game types, maps, team composition, etc, I would like to focus on the general goal of killing lots of enemies. What pairs of heroes combine well to successfully take out multiple enemies (either all at the same time or survive long enough to take them out one at a time)?

Comment: "Most synergy" is a bit of difficult judgement point and makes this question rather opinion-based. Perhaps asking what heroes synergize with a specific hero and how would be a more fitting question.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a bad question, although in it's current state it is very opinion based. Perhaps editing the question to "which hero pairs are the most deadly/do the most damage together?" would help?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I had tired to narrow it down to taking out multiple enemies because that was my main goal in asking the question (not great pre-edit) and because it wouldn't require big changes to the answer already posted. Could you maybe clarify what you mean by "most deadly"? I think that lines up closely to what I am looking for.

Comment: Most deadly probably wasn't the best wording. The better thing to look at I think is "deals the most damage together", maybe in terms of combinations of Ultimate abilities, passives, etc.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Alright. I think I see what you are saying. In that case, I think my interest is "deals most damage with standard attacks/abilities, bonus points for ultimate synergy" but that would require some changes to your answer, I think. It may be best to delete and re-ask? Though, I don't want you to lose the rep from your answer...

Comment: @Yawus what do you both think? I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41456/discussion-between-pants-and-kaizerwolf).

Comment: I agree this is rather subjective but it's also fairly broad.  As mentioned above, there are lots of different types of synergy - both offensive and defensive - and specific abilities across pairs of heroes can combo together well (e.g. a Reinheart shield in front of a turreted Bastion on the payload can kill lots of enemies, but so can a lot of other abilities - say a well-timed ice wall to funnel people through a chokepoint at an objective).  I think it'd be better to ask from the perspective of a specific hero, and even then there are many combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively open ended question, and there can be many preferences between players. Regardless, you will want characters whose ultimates complement each other.

For example, **Zarya** works well with almost any character, as her Gravity Well creates easy targets for other ultimates, such as **Pharah's** Rocket Barrage, **Junkrat's** RIP-Tire, **Tracer's** Sticky Bomb, and **Hanzo's** Dragon Arrow, to name a few.

Team Composition goes beyond Ultimates though. In my experience, a Mercy running with a Roadhog, Junkrat, or Pharah, can be a deadly combination, as Mercy can stay behind to heal and provide her damage buff, which can greatly increase the potency of these characters on the map. A damage-buffed Roadhog is nothing to snort at.

I have also seen teamwork between a Mei and a Widowmaker, in which the Mei creates an ice wall under Widowmaker so she can see over a wall to shoot. It's quite useful on Volskaya Industries when assaulting the final control point.

Personally, a duo of myself as Zenyatta and my friend as Reinhardt is fantastic, as Zenyatta can heal behind Reinhardt's shield while also decimating targets with the Discord Orb.

Again, this is a very open ended question, and some maps/gamemodes are better suited for certain pairs of characters. However, thinking ahead about who your teammates are, who you plan on playing, etc., can really help with getting a balanced and complementary team.